# Misaligned Pointer Performance

Tags: c, pointers, alignment

Aren't misaligned pointers (in the BEST possible case) supposed to slow down performance and in the worst case crash your program (assuming the compiler was nice enough to compile your invalid c program).

Well, the following code doesn't seem to have any performance differences between the aligned and misaligned versions. Why is that?

```
/* brutality.c */

#ifdef BRUTALITY
    xs = (unsigned long *) ((unsigned char *) xs + 1);
#endif
```

...

```
/* main.c */

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define size_t_max ((size_t)-1)
#define max_count(var) (size_t_max / (sizeof var))

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    unsigned long sum, *xs, *itr, *xs_end;
    size_t element_count = max_count(*xs) >> 4;

    xs = malloc(element_count * (sizeof *xs));
    if(!xs) exit(1);

    xs_end = xs + element_count - 1; sum = 0;

    for(itr = xs; itr < xs_end; itr++)
        *itr = 0;

#include "brutality.c"

    itr = xs;
    while(itr < xs_end)
        sum += *itr++;

    printf("%lu\n", sum);

    /* we could free the malloc-ed memory here */
    /* but we are almost done                  */
    exit(0);
}
```

Compiled and tested on two separate machines using

```
gcc -pedantic -Wall -O0 -std=c99 main.c
for i in {0..9}; do time ./a.out; done
```

Comment: I admit I don't understand some of your tricks. size_t is a type. So what is size_t-1 ? A small refinement is that the last iteration of sum += *itr++ reads memory beyond what you've allocated when BRUTALITY is defined. I would kill the printf and the shell invocation and looping, they might swamp any differences. Do all the timing inside the program and add a 10x loop inside the program as well

Comment: Well, xs_end points to the last element, not past the last element, in which case we would be writing past the allocated buffer. And size_t is an unsigned type, so the standard guarantees ... err just Google "SIZE_MAX portable". And no, the printf ensures that even when you use -O2 the compiler doesn't throw all the code down the drain

Comment: Oh sorry I get it -1 cast to a size_t. And yes you're right I had assumed the normal xs_end convention. I still think you should try to keep printf()'s and other heavy OS stuff out of the loop. Oh I have a strong idea - I'll go to a new answer instead.

Comment: The printf is outside the loop Bill :)

Comment: Yeah it's out of the loop but still part of the stuff you are timing, no? I propose getting the start time inside the program, do nothing but looping and adding, then get the end time. Then do any printf'ing etc.

Comment: I know I got off to a bad start with a stupid oversight, but I do have some experience with timing code. Have a look at my edited answer below. If you are getting no measured difference at all there is something wrong with your test code and I am showing you how to fix it.

Comment: The penalty for misaligned access varies lots for different CPUs (on some RISC machines like IIRC PowerPC misaligned access causes a segfault), however in general alignment to the size of the type is more than good enough, if you're worried about cache stuff, don't try to hard because malloc trys to align things so that it minimizes the amount that stuff will end up aliasing in the cache (ie booting stuff out of cache even though you might want it again soon)

Comment: see http://people.redhat.com/drepper/cpumemory.pdf for some discussion on caches and stuff like that that causes some of the main issues with alignment and performance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tested this some time in the past on Win32 machines and did not notice much of a penalty on 32-bit machines.  On 64-bit, though, it was significantly slower.  For example, I ran the following bit of code.  On a 32-bit machine, the times printed were hardly changed.  But on a 64-bit machine, the times for the misaligned accesses were nearly twice as long.  The times follow the code.

```
#define UINT unsigned __int64
#define ENDPART QuadPart
#else
#define UINT unsigned int
#define ENDPART LowPart
#endif


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   LARGE_INTEGER startCount, endCount, freq;
   int i;
   int offset;
   int iters = atoi(argv[1]);
   char *p = (char*)malloc(16);
   double *d;

   for ( offset = 0; offset < 9; offset++ )
      {
      d = (double*)( p + offset );
      printf( "Address alignment = %u\n", (unsigned int)d % 8 );
      *d = 0;
      QueryPerformanceFrequency(&freq);
      QueryPerformanceCounter(&startCount);
      for(i = 0; i < iters; ++i)
         *d = *d + 1.234;
      QueryPerformanceCounter(&endCount);

      printf( "Time:  %lf\n",
             (double)(endCount.ENDPART-startCount.ENDPART)/freq.ENDPART );
      }
}
```

Here are the results on a 64-bit machine.  I compiled the code as a 32-bit application.

```
[P:\t]pointeralignment.exe 100000000
Address alignment = 0
Time:  0.484156
Address alignment = 1
Time:  0.861444
Address alignment = 2
Time:  0.859656
Address alignment = 3
Time:  0.861639
Address alignment = 4
Time:  0.860234
Address alignment = 5
Time:  0.861539
Address alignment = 6
Time:  0.860555
Address alignment = 7
Time:  0.859800
Address alignment = 0
Time:  0.484898
```

Comment: Brilliant. This inspires me to test out more machines, including virtual hosts and clients of different architectures.

Answer (score 2):

The x86 architecture has always been able to handle misaligned accesses, so you'll never get a crash. Other processors might not be as lucky.

You're probably not seeing any time difference because the loop is memory-bound; it can only run as fast as data can be fetched from RAM. You might think that the misalignment will cause the RAM to be accessed twice, but the first access puts it into cache, and the second access can be overlapped with getting the next value from RAM.

Comment: This seems like the most sensible answer. In which case, what processor doesn't cache the overlapping memory addresses, in which case ... when would there be any relevant performance difference? Either that or my test sucks.

Comment: @EliteMx: "when would there be any relevant performance difference?" If your application accesses really lots of memory, the redundantly fetched data (and code too!) simply decrease effective cache size. Frankly, you better read the manual for your CPU. I presume you are on Intel - IA-32 or EM64T - and Intel has rather excellent documentation on that, e.g. http://www.intel.com/products/processor/manuals/index.htm .

Answer (score 1):

You're assuming either x86 or x64 architectures. On MIPS, for example, your code may result in a SIGBUS(bus fault) signal being raised. On other architectures, non-aligned accesses will typically be slower than aligned accesses, although, it is very much architecture dependent.

Comment: Nope. I'm not assuming anything. Read the first sentence I wrote. In fact seeing it in action (the bus fault, the slow access) would make me very happy. I am also going to test out the results on an ARM CPU [N900].

Answer (score 0):

x86 or x64?

Misaligned pointers were a killer in x86 where 64bit architectures were not nearly as prone to the crash, or even slow performance at all.

Comment: Tested on "AMD Athlon(tm) XP 2700+" and on an "Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU 5150 @ 2.66GHz" ... but really if you have something different feel free to post your results.

Answer (score 0):

It is probably because malloc of that many bytes is returning NULL. At least that's what it does for me.

Comment: My code gets to the printf statement (ie: malloc succeeds) ... you could try shifting by 5,6 or 7 bits instead of 4.

Answer (score 0):

You never defined `BRUTALITY` in your posted code.  Are you sure you are testing in 'brutal' mode?

Comment: Well, of course. If I had defined it you would say ... but you never tested without BRUTALITY mode :P

Answer (score 0):

Maybe in order to malloc such a huge buffer, the system is paging memory to and from disk. That could swamp small differences. Try a much smaller buffer and a large, in program loop count around that.

I made the mods I've suggested here and in the comments and tested on my system (a tired, 4 year old, 32 bit laptop). Code shown below. I do get a measurable difference, but only around 3%. I maintain my changes are a success because your question indicates you get no difference at all correct ?

Sorry I am using Windows and used the windows specific GetTickCount() API I am familiar with because I often do timing tests, and enjoy the simplicity of that misnamed API (it actually return millisecs since system start).

```
/* main.cpp */

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <windows.h>

#define BRUTALITY

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    unsigned long i, begin, end;
    unsigned long sum, *xs, *itr, *xs_begin, *xs_end;
    size_t element_count = 100000;

    xs = (unsigned long *)malloc(element_count * (sizeof *xs));
    if(!xs) exit(1);
    xs_end = xs + element_count - 1;
    #ifdef BRUTALITY
    xs_begin = (unsigned long *) ((unsigned char *) xs + 1);
    #else
    xs_begin = xs;
    #endif

    begin = GetTickCount();
    for( i=0; i<50000; i++ )
    {
        for(itr = xs_begin; itr < xs_end; itr++)
            *itr = 0;

        sum = 0;
        itr = xs_begin;
        while(itr < xs_end)
            sum += *itr++;
    }
    end = GetTickCount();

    printf("sum=%lu elapsed time=%lumS\n", sum, end-begin );

    free(xs);
    exit(0);
}
```